# Unable to call script from SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to call a script I have created from SQL developer like this.

```
@"Descargas\prueba.sql""
```

Unfortunately, it throws the below error:

```
Error que empieza en la línea 1 del comando:
@"Descargas\prueba.sql"
Informe de error:
No se ha podido abrir el archivo: "C:\Users\U358523\Descargas\prueba.sql"
```

The script is present in the directory, so not sure if I should replacing any of the characters for it to work.

Comment: There's something wrong with what you posted. Oracle complains about `"C:\Users\U358523\Descargas\prueba.sql"` not existing, which is rather different from `@"Descargas\prueba.sql""` (different directories, superfluous double quotes). If Oracle says that file doesn't exist, I believe it and suggest you to check what you're doing.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to tackle this? It happened to me some years ago and I remember the solution had something to with replacing the colon with something else but I am completely lost right now.

Comment: If I copy paste C:\Users\U358523\Descargas\prueba.sql into my file explorer, it opens the file.

Comment: It works OK for me; my .sql file is located here: `@C:\Users\littlefoot\Documents\a.sql` and executes normally when I call it from SQL Developer.

Comment: I am using a virtualized application of my SQL Developer. Can that be making a difference?

Comment: Sorry, I wouldn't know.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
@"Descargas\prueba.sql""
```

try

```
cd C:\wherever\your\file\is\descaras
@prueba.sql
```

Comment: Now it says Error que empieza en la línea 2 del comando:
@prueba.sql
Informe de error:
No se ha podido abrir el archivo: "C:\oracle\11.2.0\client_1\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin\prueba.sql"

Comment: so check and confirm the file permissions are read - or copy the file to your user's documents folder and try that

Comment: How can I check the file permissions?